# Where is that 1.1.1.1 NS coming from?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I was checking `systemd-resolve --status` that returns

```
Global
         DNS Servers: 1.0.0.1   <-------------
                      1.1.1.1   <-------------
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      ...
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 45.a.b.c
                      51.d.e.f
```

The NS `45.a.b.c` and `51.d.e.f` are set in netplan.

But, where are the public Cloudflare NS `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1` coming from?

- NetworkManager is stopped and disabled (+ reboot)
- `netplan` uses `networkd`, and the config `ip a` reflects its settings
- IPv6 (should not matter much) is temporarily disabled
- `dhcpv4` is disabled, address is static (and anyway, openwrt would assign the ISP NS addresses which are different)
- `resolv.conf` resolves locally `nameserver 127.0.0.53`
- no config in `/etc/resolvconf/*`

Netplan:

```
eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 10.1.2.3/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 45.a.b.c
          - 51.d.e.f
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 10.1.2.1
```

Comment: CloudFlare DNS servers are currently the fallback ones used by systemd: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8899, https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/11666 I suppose your specified nameservers don't work?

Comment: Actually they work. But... looking at `/etc/systemd/resolved,conf`, `FallbackDNS` is not set, but... `DNS=1.0.0.1 1.1.1.1` is set! (probably by me a long time ago, didn't remember this file!). Problem solved it seems!

Comment: Glad to see you've found the problem. Please put the solution in an Answer. You can then accept it (possibly tomorrow) and get the points. You'll also get a +1 from me because it's a good catch

Comment: Those who VTC because it's a typo - that's as may be but I would say that it's still a useful question/answer for future potential readers and therefore should remain open. The "_…as they are unlikely to help future readers_" doesn't apply here.

Comment: @roaima Thanks, did it. Name resolution is covered at so many places ....

Answer (score 4):

After reading the comment from @muru, went to check the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file, that I missed... and

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.0.0.1 1.1.1.1
#FallbackDNS=
```

found the culprit! I probably set it long ago, after systemd was implemented in Ubuntu. Commenting these lines out and they don't show anymore in the status.

Forgot about this file

NB: how many files are related to NS resolution ?! resolv.conf, resolvconf*, systemd/resolved.conf, netplan ns, dhcp ns, NetworkManager ......